# Optional chaining in Python

Tags: javascript, python

Javascript has a useful pattern called optional chaining, that lets you safely traverse through a deeply nested object without key errors.

For example:

```
const foo= {
    correct: {
        key: 'nested'
    }
}
const correct =    foo?.correct?.key
const incorrect =  foo?.incorrect?.key
```

You can also do it the old fashioned way like this:

```
const nested = foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.key
```

Does Python have a pattern as clean as this for traversing nested dictionaries? I find it particularly verbose when traversing deeply nested objects with long key names.

This is the closest I can get in Python:

```
getattr(getattr(foo, 'correct', None), 'key', None)
```

Which is pretty gross and starts getting dumb beyond two or three nestings

Comment: You could use a `collections.DefaultDict` instead of the built-in `dict` to get some behavior like this, I suspect.

Comment: `.get()` with a default value of an empty dict might be a bit better? 
 `foo.get('correct', {}).get('key')`